# PHP MYSQL query help, results not what expected

Tags: php

Hey I'm running php mysqli query:

```
<?php do { echo $row['depicao']; ?>-<?php } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)); ?>
```

The result I need should show the following

data-data2-data3-data4 etc.

However what I'm seeing is:

-data-data2-data3-data4

how can I get the "-" to not appear as the first result?

Ive tried this but I get the same result.

```
<?php do { echo $row['depicao']; echo'-'; ?><?php } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: In first iteration of `do` `$row` is __not defined__

Comment: ?? The query runs fine, it just doesn't show the results in the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
do { echo $row['depicao']; ?>-<?php } 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
```

`$row` gets defined **after** first iteration, and not **before**. That's why 
`$row['depicao']` outputs nothing. If you had `error_reporting` **on** - you would also see a notice.

So, first fix is to define `$row` **first** and then output it:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['depicao']; 
    echo '-';
}
```

But in this case your output will be ended with `-`.

So, one of the solutions is to collect values in array and `implode`'em:

```
$values = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $values[] = $row['depicao']; 
}
echo implode('-', $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using while loop instead of do-while.

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { echo $row['depicao'];echo'-';} ?>
```

The problem with do while is that it executes at least once even if the condition fails. Hence one "-" is printed in beginning even without evaluating the condition.

If the goal is just to remove the  extra "-" then it can be done with-

```
<?php do { echo $row['depicao']; if($row['depicao']!=null) echo "-"; } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)); ?>
```

Comment: That fixed it. Many Thanks!

Comment: Still you have a "-" at the end

Comment: Okay. my bad. If the goal is just to remove extra "-" then it can be done with-
<?php do { echo $row['depicao']; if($row['depicao'] != null) echo "-"; } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop instead of do...while

Because when you use do while loop it'll execute once always and then it'll check the condition and that's why you got the `-` at very first of your result.

So use while loop to check the condition, if true then code under loop will execute otherwise not.

I'll strictly recommend you to learn about loops.